# Django Map Widgets drawing polygons

Tags: python, geodjango, django-widget

I'm just wondering, what is the name of the polygon field in the [django-map-widgets](https://github.com/erdem/django-map-widgets) module for GeoDjango and whether it supports drawing polygons?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly there is not a polygon widget implemented for django-map-widgets.

And judging from this issue back from 2017: https://github.com/erdem/django-map-widgets/issues/27 where the author wrote:

> Hi All
>
> Unfournetly, I will not implement the polygon widget in the short term. I did some bug fixes and just released a new version, but I didn't catch time to implement new widgets.
>
> If anyone like to send a PR for Polygon Widget, I'm happy to help. I am closing the ticket until I have a PR.
>
> Thanks.

There will not be one in the foreseeable future.

You can instead use something like [django-floppyforms](https://django-floppyforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) which has a satisfying amount of GeoDjango widget and good documentation on how to use them: https://django-floppyforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/geodjango.html

Or (my personal favorite): [django-leaflet](https://django-leaflet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/widget.html#in-forms)

Comment: Hey @kiwis, I was wondering, did you find this answer helpful?